# If statement executes when it's false

Tags: python, nuke

I am getting "Knob already attached to a node" when i try to add a knob

i get this when i try to run my code from menu.py button.. if i run the script from the script editor i don't get the error.. why is that?

```
for i in nuke.allNodes():
    if not i.knob("tempMb"):
        if sum0 == 0:
            nuke.message("first tmp knob created")
            i.addKnob(t)
        elif sum0 != 0:
            nuke.message("second tmp knob created")
    else: 
        nuke.message("no nob created")
```

Even though **i check if there is a knob named tempMb** .. it still executes it as if there was not, when there is..
edit: "t" is earlier defined as Int_Knob...

Thanks!

Comment: Present your [MCVE].

Comment: You might find better answers on [The Foundry's forum for NUKE Python](http://community.thefoundry.co.uk/discussion/forum.aspx?f=190).

Answer (score 2):

Try the following solution:

```
import nuke

t = nuke.Int_Knob( 'tempMb', 'tempMb' )

for i in nuke.allNodes():
    if not i.knob("tempMb"):
        if nuke.exists("sum0"):
            nuke.message("First tmp knob created")
            i.addKnob(t)
        else:
            nuke.message("Second tmp knob created")
    else: 
        nuke.message("No knob created")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First I'm going to change the `elif` to just `else` because your if condition is already testing the elif condition and I don't see how that would be changing while in this code.

```
for i in nuke.allNodes():
    if not i.knob("tempMb"):
        if sum0 == 0:
            nuke.message("first tmp knob created")
            i.addKnob(t)
        else:
            nuke.message("second tmp knob created")
    else: 
        nuke.message("no nob created")
```

Second I'm assuming that `i.knob(string)` doesn't check for the existence of a knob by that name, or your code would behave more as you expected. So when I read [the docs](https://docs.thefoundry.co.uk/nuke/80/pythonreference/nuke-module.html#allNodes) it seems like a couple of things may happen:

1. The nodes might or might not be knobs in the list returned. If you know you only want knobs you could filter by class type. I think that might look like `nuke.allNodes(nuke.Knob)`.
2. I don't think a nuke.Knob.knob(str) is a test for its name or label. I read the docs as implying that your test should be: `if i.name != "tempMb":` or possibly `if i.label != "tempMb"` it depends on how you created `t`.

Moving on though, I think there may be a logical error here. If you have 2 nodes (and if you make the above changes, let's assume they're both knobs), and as you loop over all nodes the first one is the `tempMb`, then when you check the second one it won't be that and you'll try to add `t`, which I assume is named `tempMb` too. So that's why it looks to you as though the negative condition is always occurring.

You need to restructure in one of two ways:

1. Before the loop, set a false boolean, in the loop set it to true when the knob is `tempMb` is found; you may as well exit the loop as soon as this occurs. After the loop check the boolean to see if it's safe to add `t`.
2. I see a possible function [`nuke.exists(s)`](https://docs.thefoundry.co.uk/nuke/80/pythonreference/nuke-module.html#exists) which tells you if you have any "item" named `s`.

Maybe remove the loop and write the following:

```
 if not nuke.exists("tempMb"):
     # Add your knob. I'm actually not seeing `addKnob` in the docs.
```

Comment: how would you check if there is a knob or not? Since     "if not i.knob("tempMb"): " is not working in this case
edit: i tried to find some info on this on the api.. couldn't find anything though...

Comment: @masky007 read my points 1 and 2 and then follow the link to the docs, if you think that I'm on the right track (and it's hard for me to tell without seeing when you created `t` or any other node or knob) then try those suggestions. I hope they help.

Comment: @masky007 I added more so previous comment refers to first points 1 and 2. But I think the real problem is the logical issue in the moving on part. Where for every node that is not `tempMb` you add `t` to it. That doesn't sound like what you wanted to do.

Comment: but why dose the scripts runs fine if i execute it from script editor?
this only happens when i start the code through the menu.py button...

Ill take your suggestions and test everything - will let you know how it went. Thanks!

Comment: @masky007 That wasn't part of your question before but the only explanation would be that the two environments differ due to the evaluation order. menu.py is loaded during the startup, sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

`nuke.exists("Name of Knob")` will check if your knob exists. Try using that in your if statement.

More details on [Nuke forum](http://community.thefoundry.co.uk/discussion/topic.aspx?f=190&t=101399).

See also [Documentation on nuke.exists](https://www.thefoundry.co.uk/products/nuke/developers/100/pythonreference/nuke-module.html#exists)